# ionic cordova build android Error with gradle

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, build

I'm working on a new ubuntu machine.
I have installed the last Ionic version, java 8, android studio.
I have created a new blank ionic project.

When I try to run `ionic cordova build android` I have this error:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/raul/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
[11:28:59]  lint finished in 2.81 s 

FAILURE: 
Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

Someone with the same error? Know someone the solution??

**ionic info**

cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.16.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.16.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v6.11.5
npm               : 3.10.10 
OS                : Linux 4.13
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /home/raul/Android/Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

**gradle --version**

Gradle 4.1

Build time:   2017-08-07 14:38:48 UTC
Revision:     941559e020f6c357ebb08d5c67acdb858a3defc2

Groovy:       2.4.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_144 (Oracle Corporation 25.144-b01)
OS:           Linux 4.13.0-16-generic amd64

**cordova platform help**

Installed platforms:
  android 6.3.0

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

- Install oracle-java8-installer (from PPA) not sure if this is needed, but I did)
- Restart PC (not sure if this is needed)
- Run `sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java`
- Run `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java`

Above steps worked fine for me (Kubuntu 18.04).  I took the solution from [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968824/ubuntu-17-10-java-8-certificate-error/968850#answer-968850).